# create a loading bar using an dynamic incrementing value

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database, progress-bar

I want to create a loadingbar/ progressbar that loads as a value (var) increases. I cant figure out how to go around this.I have the tools. e.g. a dynamic chaning value extracted from my Firebase DB that increments on based off of a certain action.  however im unsure how to go around to creating this progressbar and how to have it load based off of the dynamic incrementing value.

Any tips?

Comment: You can use `.on("value", ...` function on the database ref object, then update your value based on the data you got from the snapshot and re-render your HTML element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below:

```js
function increaseWidth(percent) {
  let containerWidth = document.getElementById('progressBarContainer').clientWidth;  // get the container width
  let amount = Math.round(containerWidth * percent/100);      // get amount of pixels the bars width needs to increase
  let barWidth = document.getElementById('bar').offsetWidth;  // get the current bar width
  
  // if the bar width + amount of pixels to increase exceeds the container's width, reduce it accordingly
  if(barWidth + amount > containerWidth) {  
    amount = containerWidth - barWidth;
    clearInterval(bar);     // we reached 100% so clear the interval
  }
    
  let totalPercent = Math.round((barWidth + amount) * 100/ containerWidth); // calculate the total percent finished
  
  document.getElementById('bar').style.width = barWidth + amount + "px";    // increase bar width
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = totalPercent + "%";           // update the percentage text
}

// this is just to mimic generating "work done" percentage
var bar = setInterval(function() {
  let percentage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1); // generate a percentage of work done
  increaseWidth(percentage);
}, 1000)
```

```css
#progressBarContainer {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #09f;
  background-color: #000;
}

#bar {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #f00;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressBarContainer">
  <div id="bar">
    <div id="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting approach and super helpful thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using JQuery, try using the [JQuery UI Progressbar Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/). You have to first add the JQUERY UI library to your website using a `<script>` tag in the header:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-KM512VNnjElC30ehFwehXjx1YCHPiQkOPmqnrWtpccM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then initialize the progress bar with a maximum value; if you want to use percentages, that should be 100.

```js
$("#progressbarElementID").progressbar({
  max: 100
});
```

Then update by writing a percent:

```js
$("#progressbarElementID").progressbar({
  value: 74   // Or whatever percent you want...
});
```

Repeat the update function as necessary to change the progress bar.

For a more in-depth tutorial you can refer to the [API docs for this feature](https://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/).

Comment: Good answer. The only problem is that the OP didn't use any jQuery tags, so it seems he is expecting a plain javascript answer.